# First Item of fetched dropdown data in React doesn't get posted

Tags: reactjs

Hi I fetch some data and use it to populate my dropdown list and then post it to my backend but I found out that only the first item doesn't get posted, all the other fetched data get posted along with the form.  I suspect it may be because it automatically selects the first value as the placeholder value, since it's only the first value not getting posted.

```
//where I fetch the data 
 componentDidMount() {
    this.fetchOptions();
  },
  fetchOptions() {
    fetch("https://localhost:44341/api/categories")
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(json => {
        this.setState({
          obj: json
        });
      });
  },
```

```
//the handlechange method for the dropdown
handleCatChange() {
    var value = ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this.refs.categoryId).value;
    this.setState({
      categoryId: parseInt(value)
    });
  },
```

```
//the dropdown list
 <div className="drop-down">

              <select
                ref="categoryId"
                onChange={this.handleCatChange}
                style={{ width: "82%" }}
              >
                {this.state.obj.map(obj => {
                  return (
                    <option
                      key={obj.id}
                      value={obj.id}

                    >
                      {obj.categoryName}
                    </option>
                  );
                })}
              </select>
            </div>
```

I expect the first value to be sent to the backend if selected. Any help will be duly appreciated.

Comment: `First value` - try to select the 2nd and them select the 1st again.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you did not set the default categoryId at constructor

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
       // Need to set default value for categoryId
       categoryId: 0  // or whatever value
    }
}
```

handleCatChange() is called ONLY when user changes the dropdown value. If user do not interact with the dropdown, categoryId will remain as the default value.

To overcome this, after fetch API, set category ID using the first item

```
componentDidMount() {
  this.fetchOptions();
}
  fetchOptions() {
    fetch("https://localhost:44341/api/categories")
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(json => {
        // Set the default category ID
        const categoryId = json[0].id
        this.setState({
          obj: json,
          categoryId: categoryId
        });
      });
  }
```

**Edit**

```
//the handlechange method for the dropdown
handleCatChange(e) {
    var id = e.target.value;

    // Print the selected object
    const selectedObj = this.state.obj.find(obj => obj.id == id )
    console.log(selectedObj)

    this.setState({
      categoryId: parseInt(id)
    });
}

render() {
    return(
        <select
            ref="categoryId"
            onChange={this.handleCatChange.bind(this)}
            style={{ width: "82%" }} >
            // options here
        </select>
    )
}
```

Comment: thanks @jimmy5312.  What if i the catchange function was just say returning something to the console? how would I adjust the logic to log something to the console when the first item of the dropdown is selected

Comment: You mean just log the selected value to console?

Comment: You can just find for the selected using the id, then console.log() it. See the edited answer